# The name of the variable is added to the name of the column

Tags: postgresql, jpa, testing, entity

I have two entities - Group and UserGroup, they are connected with groupId. 
"\" are because postgre is case sensitive and this way we correct this fact.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"Group\"")
public class Group {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "\"groupId\"")
private int groupId;

@Column(name = "\"groupName\"")
private String groupName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "group")
List<Project> projects;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "group")
private List<UserGroup> members;


public Group(String groupName) {
    this.groupName = groupName;
}

public Group() {
}

public int getGroupId() {
    return groupId;
}

public void setGroupId(int groupId) {
    this.groupId = groupId;
}
public String getGroupName() {
    return groupName;
}

public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
    this.groupName = groupName;
}

public List<Project> getProjects() {
    return projects;
}

public void setProjects(List<Project> projects) {
    this.projects = projects;
}

public List<UserGroup> getMembers() {
    return members;
}
public void setMembers(List<UserGroup> members) {
    this.members = members;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Group{" +
            "groupId=" + groupId +
            ", groupName='" + groupName + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

And UserGroup

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"UserGroup\"")
@IdClass(GroupAssociationId.class)
public class UserGroup {

@Id
@Column(name = "\"userId\"")
private int userId;
@Id
@Column(name = "\"groupId\"")
private int groupId;

@ManyToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "\"userId\"", referencedColumnName = "\"userId\"")
private User member;

@ManyToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "\"groupId\"", referencedColumnName = "\"groupId\"")
private Group group;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "\"accessId\"")
private Access access;

public UserGroup(Group group, User member, Access access) {
    this.group = group;
    this.member = member;
    this.access = access;
}

public UserGroup() {
}

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public int getGroupId() {
    return groupId;
}

public void setGroupId(int groupId) {
    this.groupId = groupId;
}

public User getMember() {
    return member;
}

public void setMember(User member) {
    this.member = member;
}

public Group getGroup() {
    return group;
}

public void setGroup(Group group) {
    this.group = group;
}

public Access getAccess() {
    return access;
}

public void setAccess(Access access) {
    this.access = access;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "UserGroup{" +
            "userId=" + userId +
            ", groupId=" + groupId +
            ", access=" + access.getAccessName() +
            '}';
}
}
```

When I try to create a row in a table UserGroup I get a mistake:

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "group_groupId" of relation "UserGroup" does not exist

Why?  This happens on the string "em.getTransaction().commit(). It is really strange.

Comment: why use "PrimaryKeyJoinColumn" on "group" field? Should be JoinColumn, same for field "member"

Answer (score 0):

In the table UserGroup, a column:

```
 "group_`groupId`"
```

was generated (because you are using "" to preserve case sensitive.

You can edit in postgres the name for the column (and the foreing key too):

```
"group_`groupId`"   --->   "group_groupId"
```

JPA is looking for group_groupId.

Comment: The problem is, that we are students and working in a team on this project, and this error seems to be only on my side. In case of the other students with the same Group and UserGroup the right table is generated. And this is also strange then, that this situation is only  with this table .

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to answer this question. The problem was in sequence generation. When generating in embedded database, I don't know why, the generation type sequence doesn't work. Instead I used Identity type and everything started working